# Questions about Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

This question might be naive, I'm just making sure I grasp the API. Suppose you have an array of 3 objects

- Is `array.get(o)` the same as `array.first()`; and `array.get(2)` the
  same as `array.peek()`?

Suppose you have an object moving on screen

- Is `array.get(o).x` the same as `array.get(o).getX()`

By reading the API it seems to me that `x` returns position of the object while `getX()` returns the position of the mouse, or the user's finger whenever he touched the screen. But if that's true then I shouldn't be allowed to use `getX()` on an object like I did above

Comment: getX is a getter for x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Yes** and **probably**.

`Array#first()` returns the first element in the array, I.e. element 0. So it's the same as `Array#get(0)`.

`Array#peek` (or `Array#pop()`) returns the last element in the array, I.e. element `array.size - 1` (which in your case is `3 - 1 = 2`).

As for the question that `object.x` is the same as `object.getX()` depends on the definition of the `getX()` method in the object's class. Most likely they are equal since `getX()` is the typical syntax of a getter which gets the variable `x`. There's no reason to think that it returns the mouse position unless the `object` is `Gdx.input` since `getX()` in the `Input` class gets the mouse position.

Comment: I'll take your word and balint and use getX

Comment: @Lynob basically a getter method is a public method to access a private variable from outside it's class. A pretty fundamental thing in java. I recomens reading up on it.